# Dependency in Plug-in fragment?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have a main plugin project which does not depend on any of Eclipse APIs. But I do want to use Eclipse API's in one of its fragment plug-in. Will it cause any problem for the main plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a dependency (to a plug-in or a package) in a fragment, then you effectively modify the class path of the host project as well. Whether that will cause any changes to the semantics of the host project or any other fragment for the same host project, depends on the specific use in the project.

Having said all that, the normal answer is: no, it should not cause problems, unless you have code that depends on the class path - e.g. if you are using `Class.forName(...)` or similar...

One final note: when you test this, use `-clean` argument in the launch configuration to force OSGi to accept the changed dependency. Otherwise, it will be ignored.

Comment: But if I deliver my main plugin project with the fragment plugin, it will have eclipse dependencies right?